# How can I make text brighter? ios7

Tags: text, ios7, alpha

I made a view with little alpha, on this view I got text label, the text is grey, I will not change the alpha in my view. How can I make text brighter?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that the view should be semitransparent but the text should not.

You can do that by setting a semitransparent background color like this:

```
UIColor *semitrasparentRedColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
UIView *myViewWithSemitransparentBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
myViewWithSemitransparentBackground.backgroundColor = semitrasparentRedColor;

[myViewWithSemitransparentBackground addSubview:myLabel];
```